# Preciso fazer uma validação na data inicio e data fim com javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

Preciso fazer uma validação na data inicio e data fim...
Para que a data fim nao possa ser menor que a data início, mas como eu comecei a mexer com javascript há menos de duas semanas eu estou me batendo um pouco.
Seria esse caso abaixo:
Tanto para `DataInicioCurso` e `DataFimCurso` quanto para `DataInicioDisciplina` e `DataFimDisciplina`.

Teria como fazer uma validação por aqui?
Desde já agradeço!

```
function PreencherDadosTurma(data) {

    var turma = data;

    turma.IdInstituicaoDeEnsino = jq.IdInstituicaoDeEnsino.val();
    turma.InstituicaoDeEnsino.IdRedeOfertante = jq.idRedeOfertante.val();
    turma.IdCurso = jq.IdCurso.val();
    turma.Descricao = jq.Descricao.val();
    turma.QtdEstudante = jq.QtdEstudante.val().ToInt32();
    turma.DataInicioCurso = jq.DataInicioCurso.val();
    turma.DataFimCurso = jq.DataFimCurso.val();
    turma.DataInicioDisciplina = jq.DataInicioDisciplina.val();
    turma.DataFimDisciplina = jq.DataFimDisciplina.val();
    turma.EmpreendedorismoAplicado = jq.EmpreendedorismoAplicadoSim.prop('checked') ? jq.EmpreendedorismoAplicadoSim.val() : jq.EmpreendedorismoAplicadoNao.val();
    turma.IdTurma = jq.IdTurma.val().ToInt32();

    return turma;
}
```

Comment: Amigo, procure a biblioteca momentJs, ela é magica!

Comment: Olá, você pode usar o JqueryValidation. http://jqueryvalidation.org/. e um exemplo de como usa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773931/validation-date-input-min-and-max-value

Comment: Você pode usar os Validation do próprio .net, acho que é melhor se quiser posso fazer uma resposta.

Comment: @DiegoFilipePedroSantos eu quero sim, por gentileza :)

Comment: @MarianeRibeiro chegou a olhar conseguiu fazer algo?

Comment: @DiegoFilipePedroSantos Olá Diego, sim cheguei a olhar sim e consegui! Muito agradecida. Obrigada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então estou utilizando os componentes chamados CustomValidator e UpdatePanel, lembrando que tem algumas regras para inserir UpdatePanel, se precisar de maiores detalhes é só pedir:
WebForm1.aspx:

```
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >

    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" AutoPostBack ="true" ID="dataini"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" AutoPostBack ="true" ID="datafim" OnTextChanged="datafim_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator"  OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" ></asp:CustomValidator>
     </ContentTemplate>   

   </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

aqui é no behind:
WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
    protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        DateTime dtini = Convert.ToDateTime(dataini.Text);
        DateTime dtfim = Convert.ToDateTime(datafim.Text);
        if (dtini < dtfim)
        {
            CustomValidator1.Text = "Correto";
            CustomValidator1.IsValid = true;

        }
        else
        {
            CustomValidator1.IsValid = false;
            CustomValidator1.Text = "Incorreto";
        }
    }

    protected void datafim_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServerValidateEventArgs svea = new ServerValidateEventArgs("",true);
        CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(sender,svea);
    }
```