# o evento onKeyUp do java script influencia na function do CustomValidator

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Estou com uma duvida, o evento onKeyUp do java script influencia na propriedade ClientValidationFunction do CustomValidator.
  Estou dando manutenção em uma pagina aqui na empresa, e preciso validar um campo textbox para aceitar somente numero ou vazio antes de salvar em base. mas se este campo não respeitar a regra foi pedido para colocar a borda em vermelho. eu conseguir fazer a validação dos numero com uma função javascript para deixar só os numero tanto no  evento onBlur, onKeyUp, onkeypress e onChange, mais para pintar a borda do controle com o CustomValidator só funciona quando eu tiro o onkeyUp. 
E possível usar este evento do java script com o CustomValidator?

Comment: Já utilizou UpdatePanel, ou está utilizando UpdatePanel ?

Comment: não estou usando o updatePanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Web Forms usa internamente um framework localizado na `aspnet_client\{0}\{1}` para fazer a validação, etc.

Eles são, basicamente, determinada a partir da ClientScriptsLocation.

Tente substituir a função padrão, inclui a linha adicional para definir a cor **control_to_validate**.

```
document.getElmentById(val.controltovalidate).style.border='1px solid red';
```

ASP.NET

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" MaxLength="60"
    CssClass="standard_width" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" runat="server" ID="valFirstName" ValidationGroup="grpRegistration" ErrorMessage="First Name is required." Text="*" />
<asp:Button Text="Super" ID="btnSubmit" CausesValidation="true" runat="server" />
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidatorUpdateDisplay(val) {
        if (typeof (val.display) == "string") {
            if (val.display == "None") {
                return;
            }
            if (val.display == "Dynamic") {
                val.style.display = val.isvalid ? "none" : "inline";
                return;
            }

        }
        val.style.visibility = val.isvalid ? "hidden" : "visible";
        if (val.isvalid) {
            document.getElementById(val.controltovalidate).style.border = '1px solid #333';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(val.controltovalidate).style.border = '1px solid red';
        }          
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Então estou utilizando os componentes chamados CustomValidator e UpdatePanel, lembrando que tem algumas regras para inserir UpdatePanel, se precisar de maiores detalhes é só pedir:
WebForm1.aspx:

```
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >

    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" AutoPostBack ="true" ID="dataini"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" AutoPostBack ="true" ID="datafim" OnTextChanged="datafim_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator"  OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" ></asp:CustomValidator>
     </ContentTemplate>   

   </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

aqui é no behind:
WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
    protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        DateTime dtini = Convert.ToDateTime(dataini.Text);
        DateTime dtfim = Convert.ToDateTime(datafim.Text);
        if (dtini < dtfim)
        {
            CustomValidator1.Text = "Correto";
            CustomValidator1.IsValid = true;

        }
        else
        {
            CustomValidator1.IsValid = false;
            CustomValidator1.Text = "Incorreto";
        }
    }

    protected void datafim_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServerValidateEventArgs svea = new ServerValidateEventArgs("",true);
        CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(sender,svea);
    }
```

Comment: Qual a diferênça entre esta resposta e esta -> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/103401/129 ? Se o problema é o mesmo seria melhor votar para fechar a pergunta como duplicada.

Comment: @Sergio a pergunta é bem parecida, mas são diferentes lá ela deixa livre pra fazer de outras formas, aqui ele já diz que  utiliza o CustomValidator. Quanto a minha resposta tem alguma sugestão de como devo deixar?

Comment: Diego, não tenho sugestão específica. Se quiseres explicar melhor a resposta seria ótimo. Em geral perguntas que podem ter uma resposta duplicada devem ser fechadas como duplicadas. Mas agora já sabes isso :) Até breve.